# Magento: Added Newsletter Subscribe to Header | Not working on Home Page

Tags: php, magento, post

I have added a Newsletter Block to the header of my Magento site. However, when I hit the Submit action on the form it does not submit if I am on the Homepage. On Category and Product pages (and every other page) the Form submits.

The only thing I can deduce is that the Magento index page somehow prevents POST actions? The search form in the header uses GET so it's the only explanation I can come up with. I don't know why that would be the case but it's kicking my butt!

Can anybody help me figure this out? I am using default Subscribe.phtml and have added the new block to newsletter.xml - it's just strange that it won't work ONLY on the homepage.

Comment: Try to debug with chrome developers tools.Or something similar.My guess is that you have a javascript conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a validation script that appears on subscription.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
//]]>
 </script>
```

try commenting that to see if now the form get posted. if yes then may be form.js is getting added for the homepage. May this prove helpful !
Anyway I just included in the header.phtml and let me tell you its working fine, ignore the looks..[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. This is just another reason why I should expand on my super basic knowledge of JS. Can you think of any way doing this might break something else?